# "Cannot insert the value NULL into column..." SqlException while inserting a hashed value into the column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, hash, sqlexception

I am trying to insert a Murmur3 hashed value into an `nvarchar` column.

This is my code:

```
public int createUserAccount(string email, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[CreateUserAccount]"))
        {
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Trim().ToLower());

            int HashedPass = HashAlgorithms.Murmur3.Murmur3_1.Hash(
                new System.IO.MemoryStream(Utility.GetBytes(password)));

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", HashedPass.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appId", appId);

            return selectInt(com);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int selectInt(SqlCommand com)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            com.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            object o = com.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            if (o != null)
            {
                return int.Parse(o.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When I checked the value of `password` parameter that is passed through `com` object to `selectInt()` method, it's showing correct hashed value like -32xxxx.

But still I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password', table 'Accounts';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Line 17

Please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Can we see the stored procedure?

Comment: Not part of your issue, but you don't need your try/catch in `selectInt`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen actually it was my silly mistake. I forgot to create the asymmetric key that is used to encrypt password. Your hint took me to stored procedure and I saw that mistake there. Thanks :)

Comment: @RufusL Yeah I think parent method's `try` block will do the work. Thanks for the suggestion by the way. :)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the link. There is a comment there "This is much less of a concern if you’re calling a stored procedure, because the procedure parameter will have its own type, and that’s what will be checked against the underlying tables.". As you can see I am using Stored Procedures. So is it ok with them? And what about using entity framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a SQL error so check in your stored procedure because you are trying to insert null value in the 'Password' column.
Also check if your procedure has any triggers or if it is calling other procedures and if the insert is being made through the trigger or the called procedure.

Comment: Oops my bad. I forgot to add the asymmetric key for encrypting the password when I was restoring the database. Thanks @Posiedon :)